# How to change the position of listview items?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, parse-platform

I have an app which gets the data from the cloud and displays it in a listview. The data i am getting is from two source one from an API and the other one from parse cloud. The data from the API is displayed first and it takes the position of top listview items and the data from parse cloud is displayed later and takes the lower position. I want the data taken from the parse  cloud take the position in top listview items(When the data has been retrieved) and the data taken from the API to move down.

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        list.setAdapter(adapter);



    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        getIp = getIpAddress();

        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh
                .makeServiceCall(url + getIp, ServiceHandler.GET);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ads");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < scoreList.size(); i++) {

                        try {
                            ParseFile file = (ParseFile) scoreList.get(i)
                                    .get("appImage");
                            HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            String desc = scoreList.get(i)
                                    .getString("Desc");
                            String AppTitle = scoreList.get(i).getString(
                                    "AppTitle");
                            String appUrl = scoreList.get(i).getString(
                                    "appUrl");
                            String imageUrl = file.getUrl();
                            String Existing_user = scoreList.get(i)
                                    .getString("ExistingUser");
                            if (Existing_user.equals("true")) {
                                existing = true;
                            } else if (Existing_user.equals("false")) {
                                existing = false;
                            }
                            // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                            // value
                            if (AppTitle != null) {
                                contact.put(TAG_NAME, AppTitle);
                            } else {
                                contact.put(TAG_NAME,
                                        "Ultimate Voice Recorder");
                            }
                            if (desc != null) {
                                contact.put(TAG_DESC, desc);
                            } else {
                                contact.put(TAG_DESC,
                                        "DESC");
                            }

                            if (imageUrl != null) {
                                contact.put(TAG_PHOTO_URL, imageUrl);
                            } else {
                                contact.put(
                                        TAG_PHOTO_URL,
                                        "URL");
                            }
                            if (appUrl != null) {
                                contact.put(TAG_APP_URL, appUrl);
                            } else {
                                contact.put(
                                        TAG_APP_URL,
                                        "AppUrl");
                            }

                            // adding contact to contact list
                            appsList.add(contact);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                            BugSenseHandler.sendException(ex);

                        }
                    }
                    // Toast.makeText(TodaysPicks.this, scoreList.size(),
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size()
                            + " scores");

            }
        });
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_APPS);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String email = c.getString(TAG_DESC);

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    String photoUrl = c.getString(TAG_PHOTO_URL);
                    String appUrl = c.getString(TAG_APP_URL);
                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_DESC, email);
                    contact.put(TAG_PHOTO_URL, photoUrl);
                    contact.put(TAG_APP_URL, appUrl);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    appsList.add(contact);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                BugSenseHandler.sendException(e);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        try {
            if ((pDialog != null) && pDialog.isShowing()) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            BugSenseHandler.sendException(e);
        } finally {
            pDialog = null;
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }

}
```

This is how the data is displayed
http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-2687-211.html

Comment: why do you call `findInBackground`? Just call `find`

Answer (score 0):

You could create an ArrayList of a custom-defined objects which holds the different kinds of information you want. Then in the ListAdapter, return the appropriate data. When your AsyncTask returns, update the ArrayList to have your new elements come first, then call ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged.